# Change record id of lightning-record-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, dynamic, refresh, lightning-record-form

I want to change the ID of the form but it doesn't load the new record.
I have something like this:

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
          <lightning-record-form
                  record-id={visitaId}
                  object-api-name="FP_Visita_OBJ__c"
                  columns="2"
                  layout-type="Full"
                  mode="edit"
                  onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
          </lightning-record-form>
        </div>
```

And this in js:

```
visitaId=-1;
openModal = false;
visitaModal(event){
  this.visitaId = event.target.id;
  this.openModal = true;
}
```

when i open the modal the lightning-record-form is empty, how do I refresh the form to use the new id?

Comment: does `event.target.id` have the correct value? What calls `visitaModal`? A separate button?